# Keep button image in left position if button width is larger than width of button image (xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode

please take a look at the image below. I gave numbers; you will see 3 buttons.

[image]

**Button 1 size:** 375x187 Points
**Button 2 size:** 187x187 Points
**Button 3 size:** 187x187 Points

Button 1 background will be yellow. But i would like to use a button image for Button 1 like this below:

[image]

as you see, button image is square. (button image size is 187x187) So image should be stay in left side.

I tried to do this above but i couldn't see what i want. Because Xcode shows me like this:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Button size is 375x187. But button image size is 187x187. I would like to keep button image left like in the second picture. Let me share properties window for button also:

[image]

If i write image name in to image textfield in properties window
button size becomes 187x187 like in the images below

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't give the first button full width only do leading , top , aspect ratio and width same to bottom buttons ]

Comment: Dear, @Sh_Khan, Should I set an 'Image name' for background or Image textfield in Attributes Inspector Window

Comment: set image field ...

Comment: Okay, I don't give a full width. Where is leading, top and aspect ration. Are these in Attributes Inspector Window?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to get your desired result

1. Add UIView
2. Add UIButton in UIView
3. Add UIImageView in UIView and align UIImageView to the leading of UIView

Comment: Thanks but this is another issue. It should be align left, right, center .. etc. selections to set position a button image regarding to the button size if button width is larger than width of button image. @Nilesh Solanki